Clarifying a question: If $f:a\to b$ is any arrow, show that $\operatorname{true}_b\circ f=\operatorname{true}_a.$
This is about Exercise 4.2.3 of Goldblatt's, "Topoi".
NOT The Question:
Paraphrasing the exercise:

If $f:a\to b$ is any arrow, show that $\operatorname{true}_b\circ f=\operatorname{true}_a.$

The Details:
Recall:

Definition: If $\mathscr{C}$ is a category with a terminal object $1$, then a subobject classifier for $\mathscr{C}$ is a $\mathscr{C}$-object $\Omega$ together with a $\mathscr{C}$-arrow $\operatorname{true}: 1\to\Omega$ that satisfies the following axiom:
$\Omega$-Axiom: For each monic $f:a\rightarrowtail d$ there is one and only one $\mathscr{C}$-arrow $\chi_f:d\to \Omega$ such that
$\require{AMScd}$
$\begin{CD}
a @>f>> d\\
@V!VV @VV{\chi_f}V\\
1 @>>\operatorname{true}> \Omega
\end{CD}$
is a pullback square.

Also:
$\operatorname{true}_a=\operatorname{true}\circ!_a$, where $!_a$ is the unique arrow from $a$ to $1$.
The Question:
This is any such $f$, right? Or does it have to be monic?
I'm confused either way.
I can see it being monic only but I could be wrong.

Any $f$. Hint: draw a diagram.

Yes, any $f$! See @Naïm Favier's comment.
A hint for future users:
$$!_b\circ f=!_a.$$
